# unable to slice numpy array input

Tags: python, numpy

Expected output: [[1,0][1,0]]
Expected output: [[0,0][0,1]]
etc as the loops runs the range.
Error: at print statement. The loop is unable to run through the different indexes.
Error message only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
import numpy as np
field = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
 a2= np.array(field)
 print(a2)
 for i in list(range(10)):
      for i in a2[i:i+2,i:i+2]:
         print(a2[i:i+2,i:i+2])
```

Comment: Where the code says `for i in a2[i:i+2,i:i+2]:`, which `i` do you expect it to use in each of those places? How about where it says `print(a2[i:i+2,i:i+2])`? Trick question: *there is only one `i` variable in this scope*. Use a different variable name for the inner loop, and think carefully about where the inner loop should pull its values from. Try to write out your intended logic, step by step, in plain English words first.

Comment: That said: there are much more straightforward ways to accomplish this overall task with Numpy. It is not necessary to use Numpy just to store lists of numbers; if you do use it, it should be in order to take advantage of Numpy tools. Looping over (i.e., with your own `for` loop) something that you know is a Numpy array, is **rarely** the best approach to the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to print out a 2 by 2 matrix each time iterating through a2 from left to right and from top to bottom with step 1, the for loops should be like:

```
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        print(a2[i:i+2, j:j+2])
```

The outputs are:

```
[[1 0]
 [1 0]]
[[0 0]
 [0 1]]
[[0 0]
 [1 0]]
[[0 0]
 [0 0]]
[[0 1]
 [0 0]]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the matrix using a 2x2 window by using the shape of the matrix as a reference and a for loop to slide each dimension (x and y). This is a possible implementation:

```py
for i in range(2, a2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(2, a2.shape[1]):
        print(a2[i-2:i,j-2:j])
```

Answer (score 0):

That inside `for` loop should be `for j in a2[i:i+2,i:i+2]:` for it to work. it seems like

```
for i in range(10): 
    print(a2[i:i+2,i:i+2])
```

gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you have used i once then it is not an array to iterate through indexes. Why use two for loops? One for can do the job. Again no need to cast list on range.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(a2[i:i+2,i:i+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the values during the loops.  This is basic python looping logic

```
In [310]: for i in range(2):        # don't need list(range...)
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     print(a2[i:i+2, i:i+2])
     ...:     for i in a2[i:i+2, i:i+2]:
     ...:         print(i)
     ...: 
     ...: 
0              # outer i
[[1 0]         # the a2 window
 [1 0]]
[1 0]          # inner i, rows of that window
[1 0]
1              # outer i
[[0 1]
 [0 1]]
[0 1]
[0 1]
```

It does not make sense to use the inner `i` as indices to `a2`.  They are already arrays derived from `a2`.  I don't know why beginners make this mistake

```
 for i in alist:
     alist[i] ...   # i is an element of the list, not an index
```

With `i` being `np.array([1,0])`, this:

```
a2[i:i+2,i:i+2]
# a2[np.array([1,0]):np.array([3,2]), ....)
```

produces your error.

You used the first `i in range` correctly; why the change in the second?

Using a different iteration variable in the 2nd loop, and `range` again, produces are more logical nested iteration:

```
In [313]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     for j in range(2):
     ...:         print(j)
     ...:         print(a2[i:i+2, j:j+2])
```